# Mongodb aggregate using multiple filters

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am learning Mongodb aggregate function and I'm working on a query. My document looks like below.

```
[
    {
        "_id": 17,
        "members": [{
                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                "status": "pending",
                "joined": ISODate("2020-05-20T02:04:00Z")
            },
            {
                "email": "javatutorials2016@gmail.com",
                "status": "pending",
                "joined": ISODate("2020-05-20T02:36:00Z")
            }
        ],
        "messages": [{
                "c": "m1",
                "ts": ISODate("2020-05-20T02:04:15Z")
            },
            {
                "c": "m2",
                "ts": ISODate("2020-05-20T02:36:31Z")
            }
    
        ]
    }
]
```

Each document has 2 arrays: members and messages. I need to filter to one element in members (using email) and filter messages based on "members.joined" property matched against "messages.ts" property.

I tried different ways, couldn't achieve it yet. In the below query, I have hardcoded date ISODate("2020-05-20T02:36:00Z") instead of using members.joined property. How can I write an optimized query to achieve the same?

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 17,
      "members.email": "javatutorials2016@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      messages: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$messages",
          as: "messs",
          cond: {
            $gte: [
              "$$messs.ts",
              ISODate("2020-05-20T02:36:00Z") // supposed to have members.$.joined property here
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The expected result is the second element from messages that should be printed.

Comment: What do you've `ISODate("2020-05-20T02:04:15Z")` isn't it `ISODate("2020-05-20T02:36:00Z")` taken from object where `"email": "javatutorials2016@gmail.com"` ? Also do you want to filter `members` array as well to keep only object where `"email": "javatutorials2016@gmail.com"` - do you need it or members array needs to be as is original ? Can you edit question with required o/p from given sample doc..

Comment: thanks. corrected the ISODate("2020-05-20T02:36:00Z")  in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try anyone of below aggregation queries :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { _id: 17, "members.email": "javatutorials2016@gmail.com" }
    },
    /** If you need `members` array as is i.e; unfiltered in response, So instead of expensive iteration on `members` array we can get `joined` value as like below */
    {
      $addFields: {
        messages: {
          $let: {
            vars: {
              messagesArr: {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$messages",
                  initialValue: { data: [], joinedTime: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$members.joined", { $indexOfArray: [ "$members.email", "javatutorials2016@gmail.com" ] } ] } },
                  in: {
                    data: {
                      $cond: [ { $gte: [ "$$this.ts", "$$value.joinedTime" ] },
                               { $concatArrays: [ "$$value.data", [ "$$this" ] ] }, // If condition is met concat holding array with new object
                               "$$value.data" // If not just return the holding array, doesn't add current object to array
                      ]
                    },
                    joinedTime: "$$value.joinedTime" // maintaining joined value
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            in: "$$messagesArr.data" // return newly created array in `$reduce` using `$let`
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wew8Dh4iJhE)

**Ref :** [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

So above query will return filtered `messages` array & original `members` array. Just in case if you need `members` as well to be filtered then add below `$addFields` stage after `$match` ( where we're assuming `email` is unique ) doing this can help to avoid iteration on huge arrays :

```
{
    $addFields: {
      members: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$members",
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$members.email",
              "javatutorials2016@gmail.com"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

When you do above, `members` will be an filtered object. So in `$reduce` you can just do `joinedTime: "$members.joined"`.

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GUo2HJW_j-I)

Answer (score 1):

There is no state passed between aggregation pipeline stages other than the fields in the document.

The initial `$match` will ensure that *some* user in the `members` array has the email address, but in order to pull out the `joined` date for use in the later stage, you would need to either `$unwind` the array, use `$reduce`, or `$filter` to select the matching member, then you could reference that date in the `$filter` for the messages.

One possibility:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      _id: 17,
      "members.email": "javatutorials2016@gmail.com"
  }},
  {$addFields: {
      member: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {$filter: {
              input: "$members",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.email",
                  "javatutorials2016@gmail.com"
                ]
              },

          }},
          0
        ]
      }
  }},
  {$project: {
      messages: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$messages",
          cond: {
            $gte: [
              "$$this.ts",
              "$member.joined"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TWQiq_JNcGB)